# Going from a state to another state but passing through other intermediate states

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Let's say I have states for a car:

`designed`, `rejected`, `built`, `painted`, `sold`, `shipped`, and `used`

Each state can only go to a limited subset of other states, e.g.:

[image: state machine]

Going from `built` to `painted` is a **transition**.

What would be the name of the action to go from `built` to `shipped` while recording all the intermediate states?

Comment: Is it just a multi-state transition?

Comment: _**Progression**_ or its synonyms.

Comment: You would like to read about FSMs (and not of spagetti kind) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: Thanks, about Progression's synonyms: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/progression

Comment: @Swift I'm literally using a state machine :) https://github.com/gocardless/statesman

Comment: From built, you *proceed on through to* shipped.

Comment: This question would be better suited to [mathematics.se]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In graph theory, you would say that there is a [*path*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)) from `built` to `shipped`. Using an action, you would say that `shipped` is [*reachable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability) from `built`. Alternatively, you could say that `built` and `shipped` are *connected*.